# Unable to break from for statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I am having trouble breaking out of the for loop in the following code:

```
def getTakeaway():
    list = ['pizza', "italian", "chinese", "indian"]
    query = input("Please say what take away you'd like").lower()
    query_words = set(list).intersection(query.split())
    for word in query_words:
        with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
            for line in open('takeaway.txt'):
                        if word in line:
                            print (line)
                            break
    else:
        print("sorry your request could not be found")
getTakeaway()
```

The program should break a string and check the string against a list. If the string contains a word in the list, it opens a text file and pulls out a line which contains the word, prints the line and then it should break. My problem is the 'else' section, where I want it to return a message saying the request could not be found.

At the minute, it prints "sorry your request could not be found" even if it does find the word in the list. It should only print that out if word is not in my list.

I hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `break` breaks out of the inner `for` loop. The outer `for` loop always completes all iterations. You'll need some way to break out of the outer `for` loop. Like an exception, perhaps:

```
try:
    for word in query_words:
        with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
            for line in open('takeaway.txt'):
                if word in line:
                    raise StopIteration
except StopIteration:
    print(line)
else:
    print("sorry your request could not be found")
```

Comment: I prefer the use of an Exception to my answer - but would the StopIteration work in this case? Would that not get caught by the for loop and hence leave you with the same problem?

Comment: `StopIteration` will be caught if the iterator you're iterating over raises it, but that's not happening here.

Comment: Thank you - just tested it and you're quite right. +1

Answer (score 0):

The `break` belongs to a different loop than the  `else`. The `else` becomes active it the loop terminates without a `break`. While you inner loop terminates with a break, your outer loop, on which you put the else, does not.

Putting the check for the words into its own function provides a pretty readable solution:

```
def find_line(file_name, query_words):
    with open(file_name) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            for word in query_words:
                if word in line:
                    return line

line = find_line('takeaway.txt', query_words)
if line:
    print(line)
else:
    print("sorry your request could not be found")
```

Comment: This is correct, but could you elaborate?  Right now it's just a glorified comment.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of your function is like so:

```
def example():
    for item in iterable:
       for element in other_iterable:
           if item in element:
               print(item)
               break
    else:
        print('Only seen if "for item in iterable" fails to complete')
```

The break here is actually breaking out of the `for element in other_iterable` loop. That's why your else statement isn't being caught: the for statement it's associated with completes successfully.

The easiest way to resolve this is to put the inner-loop in a function. That way, you get to use the `return` keyword:

```
def example():
    def loop_until_found(iterable, test):
       for item in iterable:
           if item in test:
               print(item)
               return True
       return False

    for item in iterable:
        if loop_until_found(other_iterable, item):
            break
    else:
        print('Only seen if "for item in iterable" fails to complete')
```

One last point, when you open a file using the `with` statement you assign it to `f`. That means that you don't need to open it twice:

```
with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            print (line)
            break
```

Comment: I like the function solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function for the inner loop and move reading outside all the loops.

```
def TryWord(word, words):
    for line in words:
        if word in line:
            return line
    return ''

def getTakeaway():
    list = ['pizza', "italian", "chinese", "indian"]
    query = input("Please say what take away you'd like")
    query_words = set(list).intersection(query.split())
    with open('takeaway.txt') as f:
        takeaway_words = f.read().split('\n')
    line = ''
    for word in query_words:
        line = TryWord(word, takeaway_words)
        if line:
            print (line)
            break
    if not line:
        print ("sorry your request could not be found")

getTakeaway()
```